# Read/Write Throughput of /tmp with AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, throughput

What read/write throughput can I expect when using /tmp on an [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/)? I know this is faster than S3 or EFS (*C.f.* [Choosing between AWS Lambda data storage options in web apps](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/choosing-between-aws-lambda-data-storage-options-in-web-apps/)), and I know that I can expect about 75MB/s of read throughput with S3, but I did not find any hard numbers for /tmp.

Comment: I have never seen any published numbers for that. Behind the scenes, Lambda would be a virtualized environment running on Amazon EC2, so it's likely to be EBS storage. If you are worried about performance, then the alternative is to keep the information in-memory.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I think you're right. The table titled "Comparing the different data storage options" on this [page](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/choosing-between-aws-lambda-data-storage-options-in-web-apps/) states that /tmp is **Fastest**, while EFS is **Very Fast**, and S3 is **Fast**. I can't keep the data in memory, as it would be too expensive. I want to keep the data between invocations of the Lambda, for a few hours at a time, essentially using /tmp as a local cache for S3.

Comment: Data is maintained in memory between executions, much like storage remains in `/tmp/`. You could load the data into memory and reference it on future executions. Some good reading: [Understanding the Lambda execution environment - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/execution-environment.html) and this series: [Operating Lambda: Performance optimization – Part 1 | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein You totally made my day! Your suggestion is providing an amazing solution to a critical problem that we did not know how to solve. This is awesome!